# Session aborted when loading mailR package

Tags: r

I have used the mailR package for many years, but all of the sudden it terminates the session. I've tried to run the code outside Rstudio and reinstall R but still have the problem. Even worse, I can load the package with no errors on other computers using the very same setup (global options in Rstudio) as on my computer.

Anyone keen to help me figure out why I cannot load mailR?

Thank you

Comment: This seems like something to [take up with the package author](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR/issues). Given that the package was apparently last updated 4 years ago there’s a chance that subsequent R updates broke something. Breaking changes in R are unfortunately extremely common.

Comment: Hi Konrad. But how would you interpret that it works on 4 different PCs causing no termination of Rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

mailR is dependent on on the rJava package and all Java libraries, and this can cause issues.  Update your version of RTools, then uninstall and reinstall rJava, then mailR.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31957532)